# What is the grammatically correct way to say "if only"?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Which one is correct

> "If only I had time to eat healthy"

or

> "If I had only time to eat healthy"

The message I am trying to convey is that if I had time to eat healthy, I would for sure do it.

Comment: As the answers suggest, your second example doesn't work; however, there is one other idiomatic way of saying this: ***If I only had** time to eat health(il)y*, as in the *Wizard of Oz* classic song(s), *If I only had (a brain/a heart/the nerve)*.

Comment: Just the words "If only." are used as a slang complete sentence.  It's used as a confirming response to a statement, meaning "If that was the case, then surely"; the same sense you're talking about here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing your example to better explain the differences:

> If **only** I had a hammer to hit you with

I do not have a hammer; but I would hit you if I had one at my disposal.

> If I had **only** a hammer to hit you with

I have more options at my disposal than just a hammer. A bowling ball, a baseball bat, ... I wish I only had **one** option (the hammer), presumably so I wouldn't be trying to figure out what I should use to hit you.

---

The second one sounds very weird, even if it is grammatically correct. You need the first example for your current question.

---

There are cases where it would make sense:

> If I had only my boss to worry about, I could leave work early today.

You wish it was only your boss who could stop you from leaving work early; because you know that your boss isn't a problem. However, there are other people (more than just your boss) who are preventing you from leaving work early.

Comment: +1 for a very clear explanation. A small note—I think you probably meant to have a comma rather than a semicolon after the subordinate "if" clause in your last example.

Comment: I think the _if only_ from the first example is influencing you in the other examples. There’s no wish in “If I had only X”, it’s just a hypothetical statement. “If I had only a hammer to hit you with, you’d probably beat me to a pulp” doesn’t imply that I wish to be beaten to a pulp—it just says that’s what would happen if a hammer were all I had.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.  However, it is the first one that conveys the meaning you are trying get across.

*If only...* says that the condition that follows, *I had time to eat healthy*, is the what is preventing you from doing the last (unwritten) part, *[I would do so]*.

In your second sentence, the positioning of *only* makes it apply to *time* alone.  It's saying that *if the only time you had was for eating healthy...*

Hope this helps!